# POST XML data to url as value portion of key:value pair in post body with PHP/cURL (or anything else)

Tags: php, xml, post, curl

Ok so here's my situation. I need to POST XML data to a secure URL (ColdFusion web service) and display the returned results (returned as XML data). The requirements are as follows:

1. Must be a POST request.
2. Must use XML data string.
3. The XML data must be the value portion of a name=>value pair. (name can be anything)
4. The name=>value pair must be in the body of the request.
5. Content Type header must be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Other than that I know of no other restrictions. I am trying to do this with PHP/cURL but can't seem to get it to work. I am able to establish the connection with the web service fine but I am returning an error that indicates that no post body is being sent. Here's my code:

```
    $url = "https://coldfusion.cfm";
    $username = "xxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxxxx";
    $array = array(
        "idata" => "<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
```

`<XMLDATA1>
    <XMLDATA2>
        <XMLDATA3>Query</XMLDATA3>
        <XMLDATA4>Platinum</XMLDATA4>
        <XMLDATA5>1</XMLDATA5>
    </XMLDATA2>
    <XMLDATA6>
        <XMLDATA7>2440031317</XMLDATA7>
    </XMLDATA6>
</XMLDATA1>");`

```
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch))
            print curl_error($ch);
        else
            curl_close($ch);
```

`echo $output;`

Can someone please give me an idea what i am doing wrong? If I use REST Console in Chrome I can POST the XML data as a name=>value pair via request parameters in Request Payload options and everything functions as it should. Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Your your xml has to be a string sent via post.

Comment: Yes. It has to be an XML string as the value portion of a name=> value pair in the POST body

Comment: When I have done this I just put the xml string in the POSTFIELDS. Not an array.